# Fdroid gitlab pipeline lint failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, fdroid

I am trying to deploy my app on F-droid.org, i have followed everything they wrote in [Contributing.md](https://gitlab.com/c-ollins/fdroiddata/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and everything worked fine on my computer, Then i pushed to Gitlab [repository](https://gitlab.com/c-ollins/fdroiddata/) and the pipeline lint keeps failing each time i build and i takes up to an hour each time before the pipeline lint runs because of Gitlab job queue, i have tried several times and it fails, The F-droid lint on my computer works perfectly each time i run it. I really need help to pass this pipeline build.
[This](https://gitlab.com/c-ollins/fdroiddata/-/jobs/40010055) is the link to the error
Thanks

Comment: The link to the job has expired.  You should include the relevant bit of the log directly in your stackoverflow post.